# Difference in Recursion of ArrayList and Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

Filling up simple array recursively and then printing all contents:

```
void printArray(int[] a,int i)
    {
        if(i > 5)
            return;

        a[++i] = i;
        printArray(a,i);

        System.out.println("array size is "+a.length);
        for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            System.out.print(a[k]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Output :** ( *array size is defined in `main`* )

```
array size is 6
0 1 2 3 4 
array size is 6
0 1 2 3 
array size is 6
0 1 2 
array size is 6
0 1 
array size is 6
0
```

Now, take this simple ArrayList snippet :

```
void printArray(ArrayList a, int n)
{
    if(++n > 5)
        return;

    a.add(n);
    printArray(a,n);

    System.out.println("Size of array list is "+a.size());
    System.out.println("Content of Array list are "+a+"\n\n");
}
```

**Output :**

```
Size of array list is 6
Content of Array list are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] /*this is fine */


Size of array list is 6
Content of Array list are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] /*should have been [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]*/


Size of array list is 6
Content of Array list are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]/*should have been [0, 1, 2, 3]*/


Size of array list is 6
Content of Array list are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]/*should have been [0, 1, 2]*/


Size of array list is 6
Content of Array list are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]/*should have been [0, 1]*/


Size of array list is 6
Content of Array list are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]/*should have been [0]*/
```

**Question :** In memory implementation of `Recursion stack`, `array` output is what i understand correctly, *previous* or *below* stack holding value one less than the stack above it as `i` increments but using same implementation, why does all stacks of `ArrayList` contains value that should have been only in `top` of the recursion stack???

How is recursion implemented in case of `ArrayList`???

Comment: What you are not getting in that....... Inthe first one you have used loop based on i because value of i is different in defferent function cal(1,2,3,4,5) that's why you are getting different output for each functioncall but in the arraylist implementation you are just printing the all element so getting the whole arraylist.

Comment: in `arraylist` when the recursion list goes back to second stack...then in 2nd stack, element `5` was not filled in it....how can it be printed then???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code first fills up the Array respectively the `ArrayList` with values and then prints the content.

The only difference is that in the case of the ArrayList you print the whole list while in the case of the Array you only print elements *0* through *i*.

Since `i` is a primitive value each invocation of `printArray()` has its *own version of it*.

But Objects, like instances of `ArrayList`, are passed as reference. Thus each invocation of printArray() is working on the same `ArrayList` and not on a copy of the original instance. That is the reason why all invocations of `printArray()` print the same result when using the ArrayList.

Here is a tutorial which describes the difference between primitive types and Objects: http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/call-by-value-and-call-by-reference

Comment: in `arraylist` when the recursion list goes back to second stack...then in 2nd stack, element `5` was not filled in it, it was inserted in `arraylist` on the last `recursion call`....how can it be printed in 4th stack then???

Comment: Do you know the difference between using primitive types and Objects as parameters? I think this is the cause of your problem. I added a bit about this in my answer.

Comment: The array is still passed by reference as well, btw.

Comment: Were the array's for loop changed to a foreach loop, it would do the same thing as the ArrayList.

Comment: @captainroxors : yeah..i got it...my JAVA sucks!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You're simply telling System.out to print the ArrayList's toString method, which always prints all of its contents. You'd need to add a loop like you have in your first example.

```
for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
    System.out.print(a.get(k)+" ");
```

Then they'll do the same thing.

Comment: +1 ....this...is one solution, but still i am confused about *why* `arraylist has *all* values stored in `*all* recursion stack!

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the result after the recursion have been executed, that means, your recursion is non final (more info about tail recursion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion)) so in both cases the result is the full array/list, the difference in your first version is that your `i` variable scope is the function itself, it is not modified in the recursive call, so when you iterate printing the results you only check the N first values, but if you debug and look at the array you will see that is the complete array.

There is no difference in the recursion between arrays and arraylist, the main difference in your code is the way you show the results.

Your code with Tail recursion:

```
    static void printArray(ArrayList a, int n)
    {
        if(++n > 5)
            return;

        a.add(n);


        System.out.println("Size of array list is "+a.size());
        System.out.println("Content of Array list are "+a+"\n\n");

        printArray(a,n);

    }


    static void printArray1(int[] a,int i)
    {
        if(i > 5)
            return;

        a[++i] = i;

        System.out.println("array size is "+a.length);
        for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            System.out.print(a[k]+" ");
        System.out.println();

        printArray1(a,i);

    }
```